# Replacing jqtouch with jquery mobile

Tags: android, jqtouch, jquery-mobile

In my application, we have used jqtouch to develop the application, but now we are facing some issues with jqtouch and planning to replace it with jquery mobile.

I need suggestions that should I do this? Will it be helpful?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some things you might want to know:

1. Alpha versions are a bit heavy, thus slow on some devices. This will get better with future versions.
2. Using different versions of jquery with jquery mobile may vary in results (eg. some bugs show up in 1.4.4 only)
3. Try to use less ajax than you are used to or get to know the `.page()` method (yes, it's related :) )